# Show that the following system always has a solution for sufficiently small a

Tags: calculus

$$x+y+\sin{(xy)} = a$$
$$\sin{(x^2+y)} = 2a$$
My idea was:

Since $a$ is sufficiently small set $a = 0$ and trade $a$ as a variable.

By Implicit function theorem, want to show the matrix of Jacobin is not zero.

But after this I cannot show it.

Answer (score 0):

Define 
$$ f(X,a)=(x+y+\sin(xy)-a,\sin(x^2+y)-2a) $$
where $X=(x,y)$. It is easy to check
$$f_X(0,0)=\left(\begin{matrix}
1+y\cos(xy)&1+x\cos(xy)\\
2x\cos(x^2+y)&\cos(x^2+y)
\end{matrix}\right)\big|_{X=0}=I$$
which is invertable.